# Keras - Deep learning model not training

Tags: python, keras, theano

I have recently written and run this code to train a CNN with Theano and Keras:

```
#Building the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(1,8,182)))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

#Compiling the CNN
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['binary_accuracy'])

#Fitting data and training the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32, nb_epoch=100, verbose=1) 

#Saving weights
model.save_weights('trained_cnn.h5', overwrite=True)
```

I tested it on my CPU, and each epoch took about 3 minutes. A sample output for the first epoch is this:

```
Epoch 1/100
72000/72000 [==============================] - 204s - loss: 0.6935 - binary_accuracy: 0.5059
```

Now, I have migrated to a Nvidia Titan X GPU. I have also been forced to move to Keras 2 and thus have updated my code as follows, implementing the necessary changes:

```
#Building the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(1,8,182)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

#Compiling the CNN
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['binary_accuracy'])

#Fitting data and training the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32,epochs=100, verbose=2)

#Saving weights
model.save_weights('trained_cnn_b_2.h5', overwrite=True)
```

Now whenever I run on my GPU, the program just gets stuck saying

```
epoch 1/100
```

and nothing happens after this, even when I wait for more than 10 minutes. 
Why is this happening and how can I fix it? I haven't changed any of my code, besides the Keras functions. No errors are thrown. Where am I going wrong? Is there something wrong with the verbose command which is stopping the program from executing?

Edit 1: I have left my set up running overnight, but there is still no execution after that line.

Edit 2: I am using CUDA 7.5.17

Edit 3: This program from [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/tutorial-first-neural-network-python-keras/) works perfectly fine. It completes execution in less than 10 seconds, as expected.

```
# Create your first MLP in Keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy
# fix random seed for reproducibility
numpy.random.seed(7)
# load pima indians dataset
dataset = numpy.loadtxt("pima-indians-diabetes.csv", delimiter=",")
# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X = dataset[:,0:8]
Y = dataset[:,8]
# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
# Compile model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# Fit the model
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=150, batch_size=10)
# evaluate the model
scores = model.evaluate(X, Y)
print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
```

NOTE: I have verified that my GPU is working completely fine.

EDIT: I migrated to Tensorflow, and it had no problems with the CUDA version being below 9. With Tensorflow, the program executes perfectly.

Comment: the program itself is hanging. what version of cuda do you have. In my experience, cuda 8 with titan X (pascal) may need to build the cuda hooks for python JIT on the fly resulting in it taking a very long time... minutes... to load the first tensor on the gpu.

Comment: I'm using cuda 8. So after the first tensor is loaded, will it execute quickly? I have left the program even for 20 minutes, without any further progress below that line of output.

Comment: yeah it can take very very long sometimes. After that it will run as normal during that execution *but* next time you run the program it will again take just as long. It may be a pain but it is probably really worth it to install cuda 9

Comment: Okay. But the problem is that I don't have root permissions so I may not be able to install cuda 9. Do you know any other alternatives?

Comment: You can use `verbose=1` instead of `2` to see if there is any progress at all...

Comment: I have tried that already. It's still the same.

Comment: @modesitt I am actually using cuda 7.5. Sorry for assuming without checking.

Comment: i do not know of an other alternatives but to get someone to update your cuda @RaviTej310

Comment: @modesitt I found out from another user on the GPU that he's using tensorflow with the cuda 7.5, and it's working fine for him. So are the cuda hooks for python JIT only a problem for Theano+Keras, and not Keras+Tensorflow? Do you think I should migrate to Tensorflow?

Comment: yeah, most definitly. just make sure to install the right version to get a cuda 7 compatible verison.

Comment: With tensorflow, it works! Thanks for all the help :)